# Sorting via AJAX with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to update a list of ideas by Ajax and keep getting unknown format. I have this table:
[image]

and I'm trying to sort based on filter. I have this in my home controller:

```
  def sortable
    type = params[:type]
    case type
      when "Recent"
        @my_ideas = @my_ideas.ideas.sort_by(&:created_at)
      when "Less Price"
        @my_ideas = @my_ideas.ideas.order('price asc')
      when "Higher Price"
        @my_ideas = @my_ideas.ideas.order('price desc')
    end
  end
```

and in js file:

```
$('#filter_content p').on('click',function(){
    $('#filter_content').animate({
        height: 0
    }).addClass('open');
    $('#ideas .item').fadeOut().fadeIn();
    var type = $(this).text();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'home/sortable',
            type: 'GET',
            data: type,
            format: 'js'
        })
})
```

I initially had a respond_to do |format| format.js in my sortable method but didn't work. Anyone got any hints?

Comment: trying to refresh the list dynamically and show the items sorted

Comment: what exactly is the problem? It just looks like you're not doing anything after sorting. you should be returning @my_ideas to the js and then re-rendering using the new order

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery.ajax option to make a JavaScript request is `dataType: 'script'`, not `format: 'js'`.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

In Rails to use JavaScript as a response type, you must have an action that responds to JS (without a `respond_to` block, I believe it will by default) AND you must have a JavaScript response file (aka `app/views/home/sortable.js.erb`).

The response `sortable.js.erb` will be sent to the browser instead of a new page.

Your action looks good, is sorting. But now, we need to write code in `sortable.js` that inserts the new HTML into an element of the web page.

For example (assuming an element id-ed `#ideas` and a partial `app/views/ideas/_idea.html.erb`):

```
# app/views/home/sortable.js.erb
$('#ideas').html('<%= j render @my_ideas %>')
```

The above code will render the collection, using the partial for each `idea` into the JS code that will be received by the browser.

Thus, Ajax request goes out, JS comes back and the page is not reloaded.

Otherwise, as pointed out by others,  don't use AJAX and just turn your dropdown into links to the same page.

Comment: for some odd reason my type = params[:type] is returning nil

Comment: That's because your request body looks like this `{"Recent"}`, while your controller expects `{type:"Recent"}`. Check it out yourself :) You need to do `type = { type: $(this).text() }`, that way Rails can read the data off of `params[:type]`.

Comment: i think im getting close but im getting this error:
VM50473:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at DOMEval (jquery.self-355640b….js?body=1:83)
    at Function.globalEval (jquery.self-355640b….js?body=1:349)
    at text script (jquery.self-355640b….js?body=1:9577)
    at ajaxConvert (jquery.self-355640b….js?body=1:8725)
    at done (jquery.self-355640b….js?body=1:9193)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.self-355640b….js?body=1:9485)
not sure if its because of the sortable.js.erb

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake in the `sortable.js.erb` code. It's `j render`, not `render j`, where `j` is a shorthand for `escape_javascript`. This means that the ERB is not interpreted as File lines, which would be an issue for newlines in the HTML. Instead a newline is escaped as a string.

Comment: Thanks. I feel so close it's frustrating. I don't have any errors anymore and I've put a p to see if the method is actually updating the variable @my_ideas and it seems like it is but it's not updating the partial on the page. I have this:

Comment: $('#grid').html("<%= j render(:partial => 'idea') %>");

Comment: You're not passing the collection to your partial, just rendering the partial. Either use `<%= j render @collection %>` where Rails will try to infer the partial for the objects in collection or `<%= j render partial: 'idea', collection: @collection, as: :idea %>`.

Comment: how can i pass it back?

Comment: I tried using the :locals => { my_ideas: @my_ideas } but that wasnt working

Comment: No need to pass instance variables, they are accessible.

You're partial need to be the HTML of a single `idea`.

Comment: <% '@'my_ideas.each do |idea| %>
    <div class='item'>
      <%= link_to idea, method: 'Delete' do %>
          <div class='removegift'></div>
      <% end %>
      <div class='price'><%= idea.gift.price %></div>
      <%= image_tag idea.gift.image %>
      <h2><%= idea.gift.name %></h2>
    </div>
<% end %>
This is the partial. If i don't put the @my_ideas it crashes

Comment: Posting this much in comments, especially when the initial question is answered, is wrong. Join this chatroom and format your code properly and I will continue assisting.

Answer (score 0):

You should add .js on your URL, so your response is processed as JS, not as plain text.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'home/sortable.js',
  type: 'GET',
  data: type,
  dataType: 'js'
})
```

Comment: I think the correct way of doing the request is to use the `dataType` option from JQuery.ajax. Though I suspect that Rails still sees this as a JS request, so you're not wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I've had a similar issue recently, only resolved putting `.js` on URL, even with `format: 'js'` declared, `respond_to { format.js } ` and  `.js.erb` view file

Comment: I know that `format` makes a lot of sense, but http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ it's not an option :)

Comment: The way I see it, our answers complement each other

Comment: Passing `.js` on URL makes `dataType` irrelevant